# Do you need to know and cast the spell Scrying to use a Crystal Ball of True Seeing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Reading through the description of the Crystal Ball of True Seeing and spell I'm a little curious. Do you need to know the spell Scrying in order to cast it? Also, does it consume a spell slot when casting? For example, would a level 7 wizard, which is not high enough level yet to cast the spell, be able to use this item or not?

Answer (score 13):

The Crystal Ball is a very rare item, this makes it powerful in the first place.

The character needs to first be attuned to the magic item in order to use it and from my understanding (*on the DMG's page 159*), while touching it you're able to cast *scrying* (with a minimum save DC of 17).

This doesn't come with any limits, you can use this as many times as you want during a day and don't need to be a spellcaster or have spell slots in order to use this (again: all you have to do is be attuned to it), you can read about this on the *DMG page 141, Activating an Item: Spells*.

Comment: More precisely, this doesn't come with any limits - except those inherent to the scrying spell itself, for example, a creature that makes its save against the scrying may not be targeted for another 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in the DMG (p. 141)

> **Spells**
>
> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from
> the item. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell
> level, **doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots**, and
> requires no components, **unless the item's description
> says otherwise.**

The crystal ball doesn't "say otherwise" so you don't need to know the spell and you don't need to have spell slots.

Spell Scrolls, for example, *do* "say otherwise".